# how to search the records of a specific day

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I need to make a query (on sqlite3) and get all the records that are of a particular day for example of the day 13/02/2018
in the database I have it saved to the attribute 'annotated' as datetime
if I make a query it brings it as milliseconds. such as '1519321923630'
I tried something like this and it did not work. it does not bring me results but if there are really

```
"SELECT * from coupons where annotated = '13022018' ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the SQLite `date` function to get the date in question, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE date(annotated, 'unixepoch') = '2018-02-13';
```

This query presumes that the data is, in fact, stored as Unix ticks, or the whole number of seconds from the Unix epoch.

If your data is in fact stored as a count of milliseconds, assuming the same start time, then you should use

```
SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE date((annotated/1000), 'unixepoch') = '2018-02-13';
```

since millisecond resolution is not supported by SQLite. If the data is a count of milliseconds from an *arbitrary* start time, then you will have to find some way to normalize it before SQLite will recognize it as a valid date/time.

**EDIT** -- Forgot to include the 'unixepoch' modifier string.

Comment: Milliseconds are not one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: @CL: Edited to clarify. I suspect the OP's data is actually in Unix ticks, but it's possible that it is actually in ms, I suppose.

Comment: This query does not work with the value `1519321923630` from the question.

Comment: @CL. No, it doesn't. The specific value doesn't correspond to the specified date, either as ticks or as milliseconds. As I said, if the data is in fact elapsed milliseconds from an _arbitrary_ starting point, it will have to be normalized.

Comment: It's a perfectly valid milliseconds value (2018-02-22 17:52:03). But you handle it as Julian days.

Comment: @CL Ahh, thanks for _finally_ saying that I forgot to add the 'unixepoch' modifier.